# Can you forfeit or surrender?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

At some point it may become evident that it is impossible to complete your minimum number of objectives. Can you surrender or forfeit at this point, or must you continue playing things out until you actually lose? This could have consequences in terms of population loss due to plague cubes, exposure, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cannot forfeit**

From the [Season 1 FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1470601/compiled-faq-spoilers-hidden-each-month-hidden-sep):

> Is it legal to quit a game without finishing it because it's a lost cause, in particular, this would prevent additional panic stickers from being placed in case of outbreaks. Or, are we forced to sit there and see it through to the end?
>
> > You are supposed to play until you actually lose.

So unless the Season 2 rulebook specifically states otherwise, it is reasonable to apply this rule to both seasons. The rulebook justification for this FAQ entry is that the rules for how the game can end do not include forfeiting as one of the ways it can end. The rulebook lists all possible ways for the game to end.

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, continuing to play the game has consequences. These have lasting effects on the game, and are part of the game. If you forfeit when you think you are losing then you are cheating as these consequences do not happen and you are making the game easier in subsequent months.

You should play the game to the best of your teams ability until the losing conditions are met. You can start to ignore objectives in favour of controlling the negative effects. For example, you can counter population loss from plague cubes by building supply centers.

My group has won games we thought we were sure to lose, and lost games we thought we were sure to win. It's part of playing the game.